# `Node.js` and/or other Javascript offshoots' performance, stability and speed relative to non-JS frameworks (Rails, Django...)

Tags: javascript, python, ruby-on-rails, node.js, model-view-controller

I find myself often needing performance & speed references for friends who still don't believe a Node.js or other Javascript-derived implementation or application can compete with those powered by Rails, Pure Ruby, `.NET`, Python and similar setups.

I have seen very impressive reports on this, with graphs and eyecandy, but when I need them, I can never find them.
So maybe we can use this question to build a list of viable resources for "selling" a tech person/manager on `Node.js` as a viable solution. Or add citable facts to the thread

Thanks in advance.

Comment: node.js is very fast. your best proof is letting them test it

Comment: also depends on your application, I guess.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- [v8 faster then php/python, 3x slower then C++](http://blog.famzah.net/2010/07/01/cpp-vs-python-vs-perl-vs-php-performance-benchmark/)
- [node.js vs tornade](http://www.ostinelli.net/a-comparison-between-misultin-mochiweb-cowboy-nodejs-and-tornadoweb/)
- [Express vs Sinatra](http://tjholowaychuk.com/post/543953703/express-vs-sinatra-benchmarks)
- [Node.js vs apache/PHP](http://blog.raducojocaru.com/2010/07/02/nodejs-vs-php-apache/)
- [Node.js vs nginx](http://goran.krampe.se/2011/03/14/node-js-vs-nginxsqueak-part-1/)
- [Node.js in language benchmark game](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/which-programs-are-fastest.html)

Feel free to expand

Answer (score 7):

Node.js is beating other platforms, sure. But it's not it's raw speed (V8), it's the sophisticated event-driven model which powers the node.js platform ;)

Comment: Right, looking for benchmarks which show what good use of the model can produce.

Comment: I agree with spot that this does not answer question at all. Nevertheless I don't like down-voting(unless answer really bad) so I won't do that...

Comment: @Alfred, It may not answer the question, but perhaps it helps to understand why it may be fast. For example, it might not be faster if an app is "ported" from another language and does not take advantage of the "event-driven model"...

Comment: Yes. Nothing compares to Node.js's event-driven model.

Comment: Just imagine Node.js's event-driven model on quantum computers... It's a perfect relationship.

Answer (score 1):

These are the best articles I've come across comparing nodejs performance to python:

[Python v/s node v/s pypy](http://blog.kgriffs.com/2012/10/23/python-vs-node-vs-pypy.html)

[STAND BACK... I'M GOING TO TRY SCIENCE!](http://blog.kgriffs.com/2012/11/13/python-vs-node-vs-pypy-benchmarks.html)